# Logic to handle multiple ActiveX Check Box and Spinner controls on Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have four ActiveX Check Box controls and four ActiveX Spinner controls on Sheet1 of my workbook.
Currently, I have a nested IF Then Else checking the value of each checkbox and spinner control.

I need to add the ability to handle up to all four checkboxes and then set my msgBox properties depending on which checkboxes have been selected.
Additionally, I would like the ability to update the spinner controls while every possible combination of check box is selected.

**Here is the code for the checkboxes:**

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub TransformData(PolySaturday%, CaSaturday%, DhSaturday%, DoorsSaturday As Integer)

Dim Wk1Date As Date
Dim Wk2Date As Date
Dim Wk3Date As Date
Dim Wk4Date As Date

Wk1Date = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
Wk2Date = Sheet1.Range("A15").Value
Wk3Date = Sheet1.Range("A26").Value
Wk4Date = Sheet1.Range("A37").Value

' Code to update Saturday capacity
With ActiveSheet
            
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value  Then
      
        MsgBox "Saturday Capacity for " & Wk1Date & " Showing"
          
        Sheet1.Range("C4").Value = PolySaturday
        Sheet1.Range("D4").Value = DhSaturday
        Sheet1.Range("F4").Value = CaSaturday
        Sheet1.Range("E4").Value = DoorsSaturday
          
        Sheet1.Range("C16").Value = PolySaturday
        Sheet1.Range("D16").Value = DhSaturday
        Sheet1.Range("F16").Value = CaSaturday
        Sheet1.Range("E16").Value = DoorsSaturday
          
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.CheckBox2.Value = True Then
      
        MsgBox "Saturday Capacity for " & Wk2Date & " Showing"
            
        Sheet1.Range("C16").Value = PolySaturday
        Sheet1.Range("D16").Value = DhSaturday
        Sheet1.Range("F16").Value = CaSaturday
        Sheet1.Range("E16").Value = DoorsSaturday
      
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.CheckBox3.Value = True Then
            
        MsgBox "Saturday Capacity for " & Wk3Date & " Showing"
           
        Sheet1.Range("C27").Value = PolySaturday
        Sheet1.Range("D27").Value = DhSaturday
        Sheet1.Range("F27").Value = CaSaturday
        Sheet1.Range("E27").Value = DoorsSaturday
      
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.CheckBox4.Value = True Then
            
        MsgBox "Saturday Capacity for " & Wk4Date & " Showing"
            
        Sheet1.Range("C38").Value = PolySaturday
        Sheet1.Range("D38").Value = DhSaturday
        Sheet1.Range("F38").Value = CaSaturday
        Sheet1.Range("E38").Value = DoorsSaturday
    
    Else
      
        MsgBox "Regular Work Week Showing"
            
        Sheet1.Range("C4").Value = Sheet4.Range("C2").Value
        Sheet1.Range("D4").Value = Sheet4.Range("C4").Value
        Sheet1.Range("F4").Value = Sheet4.Range("C3").Value
        Sheet1.Range("E4").Value = Sheet4.Range("C5").Value
            
        Sheet1.Range("C16").Value = Sheet4.Range("C2").Value
        Sheet1.Range("D16").Value = Sheet4.Range("C4").Value
        Sheet1.Range("F16").Value = Sheet4.Range("C3").Value
        Sheet1.Range("E16").Value = Sheet4.Range("C5").Value
                
        Sheet1.Range("C27").Value = Sheet4.Range("C2").Value
        Sheet1.Range("D27").Value = Sheet4.Range("C4").Value
        Sheet1.Range("F27").Value = Sheet4.Range("C3").Value
        Sheet1.Range("E27").Value = Sheet4.Range("C5").Value
                
        Sheet1.Range("C38").Value = Sheet4.Range("C2").Value
        Sheet1.Range("D38").Value = Sheet4.Range("C4").Value
        Sheet1.Range("F38").Value = Sheet4.Range("C3").Value
        Sheet1.Range("E38").Value = Sheet4.Range("C5").Value
           
    End If
     
End With

End Sub
```

**And the code for the Spinners:**

```vb
Public Sub UseHolidayData()

    With ActiveSheet
        
        If Sheet1.SpinButton1.Enabled And Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        
            Sheet1.Range("C4").Value = Sheet4.Range("F2").Value
            Sheet1.Range("D4").Value = Sheet4.Range("F4").Value
            Sheet1.Range("E4").Value = Sheet4.Range("F5").Value
            Sheet1.Range("F4").Value = Sheet4.Range("F3").Value
        
        ElseIf Sheet1.SpinButton2.Enabled And Sheet1.CheckBox2.Value = True Then
            
            Sheet1.Range("C16").Value = Sheet4.Range("F8").Value
            Sheet1.Range("D16").Value = Sheet4.Range("F10").Value
            Sheet1.Range("E16").Value = Sheet4.Range("F11").Value
            Sheet1.Range("F16").Value = Sheet4.Range("F9").Value

        ElseIf Sheet1.SpinButton3.Enabled And Sheet1.CheckBox3.Value = True Then
        
            Sheet1.Range("C27").Value = Sheet4.Range("F14").Value
            Sheet1.Range("D27").Value = Sheet4.Range("F16").Value
            Sheet1.Range("E27").Value = Sheet4.Range("F17").Value
            Sheet1.Range("F27").Value = Sheet4.Range("F15").Value
        
        ElseIf Sheet1.SpinButton4.Enabled And Sheet1.CheckBox4.Value = True Then
            
            Sheet1.Range("C38").Value = Sheet4.Range("F20").Value
            Sheet1.Range("D38").Value = Sheet4.Range("F22").Value
            Sheet1.Range("E38").Value = Sheet4.Range("F23").Value
            Sheet1.Range("F38").Value = Sheet4.Range("F21").Value
            
        Else
        
            Sheet1.Range("C4").Value = Sheet4.Range("E2").Value
            Sheet1.Range("D4").Value = Sheet4.Range("E4").Value
            Sheet1.Range("E4").Value = Sheet4.Range("E5").Value
            Sheet1.Range("F4").Value = Sheet4.Range("E3").Value
            
            Sheet1.Range("C16").Value = Sheet4.Range("E8").Value
            Sheet1.Range("D16").Value = Sheet4.Range("E10").Value
            Sheet1.Range("E16").Value = Sheet4.Range("E11").Value
            Sheet1.Range("F16").Value = Sheet4.Range("E9").Value
            
            Sheet1.Range("C27").Value = Sheet4.Range("E14").Value
            Sheet1.Range("D27").Value = Sheet4.Range("E16").Value
            Sheet1.Range("E27").Value = Sheet4.Range("E17").Value
            Sheet1.Range("F27").Value = Sheet4.Range("E15").Value
        
            Sheet1.Range("C38").Value = Sheet4.Range("E20").Value
            Sheet1.Range("D38").Value = Sheet4.Range("E22").Value
            Sheet1.Range("E38").Value = Sheet4.Range("E23").Value
            Sheet1.Range("F38").Value = Sheet4.Range("E21").Value
            
        End If
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I feel this could be done using a for each loop.

Comment: Sometimes there is no quick way and you need to code all possibilities.

Comment: Note also that your `If...ElseIf..` statement places a priority on the check boxes that you may not want.

Comment: You can use the `class module` approach for loop all the checkbox in your worksheet, it work for me last, check this https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/class-modules-for-checkboxes.957879/

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the quick replies. I will take a look at the suggested resources and see if I can dig up a new method to try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are trying to deal with combinations of checkbox selections but here is an example similar to a [MVC framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller). Essentially the code is separated into logical components.

```vb
Public Sub TransformData(PolySaturday%, CaSaturday%, DhSaturday%, DoorsSaturday As Integer)

     ' Code to update Saturday capacity
    Dim wkDate(4) As Date, rng(4) As Range, ar0, ar
    
    ' data
    With Sheet1
        wkDate(1) = .Range("A2").Value
        wkDate(2) = .Range("A15").Value
        wkDate(3) = .Range("A26").Value
        wkDate(4) = .Range("A37").Value

        Set rng(1) = .Range("C4:F4")
        Set rng(2) = .Range("C16:F16")
        Set rng(3) = .Range("C27:F27")
        Set rng(4) = .Range("C38:F38")
        ar0 = Array(.Range("C2"), .Range("C4"), .Range("C5"), .Range("C3"))
    End With
    ar = Array(PolySaturday, DhSaturday, DoorsSaturday, CaSaturday)

    ' controls
    Dim msg As String, i As Integer, chkBox(4) As Boolean
    chkBox(1) = ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value
    chkBox(2) = ActiveSheet.CheckBox2.Value
    chkBox(3) = ActiveSheet.CheckBox3.Value
    chkBox(4) = ActiveSheet.CheckBox4.Value

    ' model
    For i = 1 To 4
        If chkBox(i) Then
            msg = msg & wkDate(i) & ", "
            rng(i).Value2 = ar
        Else
            rng(i).Value2 = ar0
        End If
    Next

    ' view
    If msg = "" Then
        msg = "Regular Work Week Showing"
    Else
        msg = "Saturday Capacity for " & msg & " Showing"
    End If
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: CDP1802, thanks so much for responding with an answer. I am trying to figure out how to enable the ability to deal with combinations of checkboxes, but I think I could still use this. I am a little familiar with MVC and MVVM. I didn't even think to use that architecture here so thanks.

Comment: Implemented your suggested code and it works beautifully. Thanks so much @CDP1802

Comment: @Brandon Do you think you can apply the same to spinners ?

Comment: I thought that maybe I could, so I tried using the MVC pattern in the same way, although I couldn't quite get it figured out. My current implementation uses nested If statements, which seems to work fairly decent, although the code is a bit unruly. I will continue playing around with it, though eventually, I am looking at creating this program in Power BI.